# How to change object from hard-coded to dynamic properties in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Using TypeScript 2.2 & Angular in Visual Studio MVC app, I have an object ("headers") that stores header names for a set of data.  The object is currently hard-coded in advanced.  I need to change this to be dynamically populated depending on the data.  Eventually, this data is exported to CSV.  Currently, the code is similar to the following:

```
let output = (this.allData);
let headers = {};
let formattedItems = [];
let csvData: any;
let fileName = "file.xls";
headers = {
   customerName = "CustomerName",
   productName1 = "Product Name 1",  
   productName2 = "Product Name 2",
   monthYear = "Month/Year"   
};
output.forEach((item) => {
     formattedItems.push ({
     customerName:  (item.Id > 0 ) ? item.Name : '',     
     productName1:  (item.Id > 0 ) ? item.Count : '',     
     productName2:  (item.Id > 0 ) ? item.Count : '',   
     monthYear:   (item.Id > 0 ) ? item.SaleDate: '',  
  });
});
csvData = this.exportCsv(headers, formattedItems);
this.exportCSV(csvData, fileName);
```

I need to revise the code to do something like the following:

1. loop through the data
2. first, get column names
3. second, append data rows accordingly

   headers = {
       customerName = "CustomerName",
        //  if (columnName like "Product")
        //  then create new column name;
       monthYear = "Month/Year"
   };

The resulting file will change from having only two "Product Name" columns:

***|Customer Name|  Nike Shoe |  Adidas Shoe |  Mar2012***

to a variable number of "Product Name" columns:

***|Customer Name|  Nike Shoe |  Adidas Shoe |  Reebok Shoe |  New Balance Shoe| 
   Mar2012***

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing headers to an array then dynamically added the data to the end of the array:

```
let headers = [];
headers = ['CustomerName', 'Month/Year' ]
output.forEach((item) => {
    formattedItems.push ({
    customerName:  (item.Id > 0 ) ? item.Name : '',          
    monthYear:   (item.Id > 0 ) ? item.SaleDate: '',  
  });
});
//Dynamically add an extra column for each product
for (let x = 0; itemsFormatted.length > x; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; this.products.length > y; y++) {
      if (x == 0) {
        //Add new header name to array
        headers.push(this.companyOnboarders[y].name);
      }
       //Add data for corresponding header
       itemsFormatted[x][this.products[y].name] = this.products[y].count
   }
}

 csvData = this.exportCsv(headers, formattedItems);
 this.exportCSV(csvData, fileName);
```